# how to set change gsl::final_action inside sub-scope

Tags: c++, guideline-support-library

How can I set a different `gsl::final_action` inside an `if` statement, since assignment constructor on `final_action` is deleted? In the example below, I only want to `create` and `delete` a resource if `condition`, but `delete_resource` should be called at the end of the parent scope, not the `if` block.

```
some* resource = nullptr;
auto cleanup = gsl::finally([] {});
if (condition) {
  resource = create_resource();
  cleanup = gsl::finally([&] { delete_resource(resource); });  // ERROR
}
```

Comment: Setup outside the if block?

Comment: ```some* resource = nullptr;
if (condition) {
  resource = create_resource();
}
auto cleanup = gsl::finally([&] { /*if (resource)*/ delete_resource(resource); });```?

Comment: One way would be to check for `condition` inside the lambda function: 
`auto cleanup = gsl::finally([&] { if (condition) delete_resource(resource); });`

Comment: `free`/`delete` work on null pointer, which is good. I don't know for `delete_resource`, so the possible check. Checking `condition` is less related.